# After test:report:chrome Report generation done, Terminal not closing the instance, it keeps running

Tags: reactjs, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver, webdriver-manager

I am using protector, selenium for running the UI automation.

For chrome driver I am using webdriver-manager for testing the UI Automation. It run successfully, browser also close but it keeps running the terminal instance can anyone help me on this?

```
config.directConnect = false;
        config.seleniumAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub";
        config.capabilities.chromeOptions = chromeOptions = {
          args: [
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-infobars",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-extensions",
            "--log-level=3",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--start-maximized"
          ].concat(isCI ? ["--headless"] : []), // run in headless mode on the CI server
          prefs: {
            "download.default_directory": downloadDir
          }
        };
        config.serenity = {
          outputDirectory: `${process.cwd()}/test_reports_chrome`,
          runner: "cucumber",
          crew: [
            ArtifactArchiver.storingArtifactsAt("./test_reports_chrome"),
            ConsoleReporter.forDarkTerminals(),
            Photographer.whoWill(TakePhotosOfInteractions), // or Photographer.whoWill(TakePhotosOfFailures),
            new SerenityBDDReporter()
          ]
```

[image: Terminal Instance]

Comment: Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `-r` for script in package.json

```
"test:chrome": "npm-run-all -p -r webdriver:chrome execute:chrome",
```

`-p` = Run commands in parallel.

`-r` = Kill all commands when one of them finishes with zero.

Running `npm run test:chrome` will start Selenium driver, start http server (to serve you files) and run protractor tests. Once all tests are finished, it will close the http server and the selenium driver.